# How to fix data not displaying on DataTables in PHP, HTML

Tags: php, html, ajax, datatables

I've just recently discovered DataTables and would like to implement in my web. Followed the instructions for SSP data but it failed to output my data.

I've tried some of the solutions from several other websites but none works.

index.php

```
<script>
function() {
$('#staff').DataTable( {
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'data.php',
        type: 'POST'
    };
} );
}
</script>
```

data.php

```
<?php

$table = 'staff';

$primaryKey = 'staff_id';

 $columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'staff_id', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'grade',  'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'name',   'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'position',     'dt' => 3 ),
array( 'db' => 'cost_centre',     'dt' => 4 ),
array( 'db' => 'station',     'dt' => 5 ),
array( 'db' => 'ic_number',     'dt' => 6 ),
array( 'db' => 'status',     'dt' => 7 )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '',
'db'   => 'feldatransport',
'host' => 'localhost'
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
?>
```

I would like the data to display in my staff table.

EDIT: I uploaded my file to my repo. [Github](https://github.com/HDI1234/problems.git)

UPDATE: Issue has been solved. It was my arrangement of scripts. I put Jquery script lastly thus DataTables isn't able to function properly. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: What error are you facing after this script ?

Comment: No data displaying on my table.

Comment: Show your output what you are getting after json encode.

Comment: {
"draw":0,
"recordsTotal":646,
"recordsFiltered":646,
"data": 
   [["1100108","8","Zamros Rofdi Bin Mohd Ros","Eksekutif 
    Kanan","442011055","HQ-MTO","701111065301","0"], 
    ["1100166","G4O","Shariza Binti Abu Bakar @ Harun","Kerani 
    Kanan","443011010","HQ-Jawat&Tadbir","750223025604","0"]

Comment: Posting on Data-table.net forums are very useful as it’s very specialized code. Sometimes you don’t get an answer here.

Comment: @JeffBezos alright thanks will try my luck there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your  tag look something like this? The order of which scripts you import first (or missing one) can throw the entire datatables plug-in off.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>DataTables Server-Side Processing</title>

   <!--       -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- datatable lib -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

I have a running datatables server-side here: https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/
Sometimes (I do not know why), you have to use $_POST not $_GET in the server.php even though the datatables example uses $_GET. That could be one issue. Anyway, here is my working code. 
**Server.php**

```
<?php
$table = 'employees';
$primaryKey = 'id'; // Table's primary key

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'zip',   'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'date',     'dt' => 4 ),
     array( 'db' => 'updated',     'dt' => 5 ),
);

$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'username',
    'pass' => 'password',
    'db'   => 'database',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_POST, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
?>
```

Lastly, posting on datatables.net forums is very helpful as this is very specialized code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried both methods still not working. Will try the datatable forums. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, let me know what they say. Some of them over there really know their stuff.

Comment: added in another attempt of solution. your script tags could be in wrong order possibly.... i see kevin responded to your datatables forum post, he is one of the best.

Comment: also, probably wont make any difference but i would have `$(document).ready()` like how in the actual example, not function

Comment: cool! let me know if you have any other issues. trying to master datatables so it gives me practice too!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to pass value with " ". In my case it is worked with "".

```
ajax: {
        url: "data.php",
        type: "POST"
    };
```

Please refer my datatable code if you found useful then revert.

```
ajax : {
                    url : "MainController",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : {
                        action : "getAssetListJSON"
                    }
                },
                columns : [ {
                    data : "AssetName",
                    className: "center"
                }, {
                    data : "HolderName",
                    className: "center"
                }
                ]
            })
```

;

Comment: Tried that before still the same problem

Comment: I have updated section with my working code. In case you found useful.

Comment: I have tried your code but it's still the same. I'll try asking the datatables forum. Thanks for the help!